# Paramiko: opening a background process

Tags: python, bash, ssh, paramiko, gnu-screen

I'm using Paramiko to SSH into a remote server and I'd like to monitor a background process running on that server using screen.

I successfully created a client and was able to print stdin/stdout/stderr using the below code:

```
import paramiko

cert = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("key.pem")
c = paramiko.SSHClient()
c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
c.connect(hostname="hostname.compute.amazonaws.com", username="ubuntu", pkey=cert)
stdin, stdout, stderr = c.exec_command('ls')
```

However, when I try the command I want to run:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = c.exec_command('screen -d -r 23099')
```

I get the error, 'Must be connected to a terminal.\r\n'. Could you explain what I'm misunderstanding about Paramiko, and if monitoring a screen output in real-time is possible? The user I'm SSH'ing with is the same user that owns the screen, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: to fix the error, pass `get_pty=True` to `exec_command()`. but its not a good idea to "monitor" a screen session with paramiko.

Comment: whats your real requirement? can you just `ssh -t user@host screen ...`?

Comment: Thanks for the help! understood - I have an AWS server with background processes on 3 screens, and aiming to build a iOS tool (for personal use) to see the status of these processes and run common commands from my phone.

Comment: I looked into the -t flag and it sounds like I absolutely should have done ```ssh -t host screen -r PID```, so thank you! Using this project to learn more about bash, http streaming, etc :)